# In manga is there a name for exchange of dialogue between characters that makes a point?

Tags: manga-production

Suppose you want to show that three of the characters have a close relationship spanning back to primary school. Then entire point of the dialogue is to enforce this.

Is there a name for this type of exchange or dialogue? Dialogue that makes a point.

PS. I remember reading somewhere that there is is a particular type of manga where you are only allowed to use four scenes to make this type of point. It's like a punchline or a gag.

Comment: A 'story within a story', where you tell a very brief account of separate events to make or explain a point is called an 'anecdote', and isn't isolated to manga alone. A manga that tells its story in 4 panel segments is called a 4koma. Do either of these describe what you're after?

Comment: You're close, I'm looking for a kind of synonym to "meme" but not so general. Essentially the point of the 4koma would be to expose some cliche or a bit size joke, so I need a word for the "conclusion" that it makes. For "memes" for example one can discern a "use-case" where you encounter a situation and relay that "meme" as a perfect response, or an all encompassing conclusion. So every time you want to ...insert word... (make a 4koma) about some peculiarity of life you use this.

Comment: I'm not too sure then, unfortunately. Just for clarity, are you asking more about what you would call the 'climax' panel of a 4koma? (Or what you'd call the contents of said panel?)

Comment: Now that I think about it, with your references, I'm asking for a synonym for Yonkoma as a unit. Let's call it "a sketch". In a manga volume, for example, the first n panels discuss some subject, then the setting changes and some other part of the story is discussed, and so on.

Comment: One of these settings is "Life at the seaside" for example, and the author uses 3-4 sketches (one in the house, one playing volleyball, one swimming and another just sunbathing) to make some points that enforce the "Life at the seaside" story. This sketch where the setting doesn't change, characters are rather set (one or many may enter or exit) where the entire discussion revolves around a specific person or activity. Does it have a name? a generic one... PS. Does the climax panel have a specific name and/or characteristic?

Comment: Right, I get what you're asking now, but I don't think I know the answer, sorry :L And the last (climax) panel of a 4koma is usually just the place where the punchline is, I can't think of any special characteristics aside from that. The Wikipedia page on 4komas calls the last panel "Ketsu (結)", if that helps.

Comment: @unmircea While in the traditional conception of Japanese narrative, you would probably call the fourth panel of a 4koma the _ketsu_ / "conclusion", in casual conversation, one would more likely call it the _ochi_, which just means "punchline".

Comment: I've seen the sort of group of connected 4koma strips that you mention [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/24392/7579#comment35198_24392) called a "scene" or "chapter". In the tankoubon, each one has its own title page, like the chapters in traditional multikoma manga. Is that what you're asking about? I'm interested in this question, but right now, between the main question and the comments, things are pretty muddled; if you could edit the question itself to more clearly explain what you're looking for, that would be a big help.

Comment: True! We're close but no cigar. I guess the closest in your answer is a "scene" or "theme". To detail a little bit, one such scene would show the character chemistry, how in a certain "context" a different mix of characters end up with different results. The "theme" of loneliness is one example, throughout a manga (multiple volumes) this context is repeated again and again and character's personalities are explored in how they deal with the situation.

Comment: The characters themselves might be completely different or just the same character at a different time in their lives and they go through this "wheel of life" again and so on... I guess "theme" is good but too general... IDK It seems like a game really, imagine a baseball manga. The game is there and every player takes turns to be the batter. It seems they all have to go through this "game" and we explore each of their personalities under the pressure to perform. Taking characters like this and having them take turns to play the role in the same "game" to see how it feels.

Comment: It's been a long time, but could you update your question with info from the comments? I'm curious and interested to research this question, but there are many terms provided already, which don't seem to answer your question. So, to not put this question in limbo (and also housekeeping this site), could you update it when you're free? Thanks!

Comment: Nice reminder! I kind of settled on some explanatory terms but forgot to come back and answer. The "characters" play out their lives in a "setting". Dictionary:  the time, place, and circumstances in which something occurs or develops. So the question still stands... Another good example I managed to figure out, in the case of baseball the answer to my question is a "play". Baseball is the "game" and there a roles each player has to take on for this event to "play" out. One is the batter, one is the catcher, first baseman etc... when all roles are covered, a "play" starts.

Comment: Pitcher throws ball in direction of the batter, the batter swings he may or not hit the ball and so on... when the "play" is over some things are decided, like who the loosing team was, the score based on rules and so on. In the case of manga, multiple characters would "attend" such a "setting". One is John A and three young girls. John A is the protagonist, a high school student, while the two others are, one a yandere, a tsundere and an innocent girl (don't know the name). Now a "play" in this situation would be an exchange of lines that cements their roles as yandere, tsundere etc

Comment: You don't know which one is what in the beginning of the "play" you might have some idea based on your past experience, but when this "setting" "play"s out you are sure which is which.